# Blank Pop-up when used with Azure AD B2C

Tags: electron, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

**Electron Version: 8.2.5**

**Expected Behavior:**
A visible pop-up with Azure AD B2C login

**Actual Behavior**
Blank screen with only close, minimize and maximize icon

This is the actual screen I am supposed to get in the pop-up.
Azure AD B2C Login
[Actual Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hktr9.png)

Instead I am getting the blank pop-up as shown below.
[Blank pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIY4F.png)

I am using `msal.js` for authentication.

```
npm Package - msal - Version 1.3.2
Electron Version: 8.2.5
```

Pop-up is working fine while I run in the development mode. But when I deploy the package and run the Windows Installer package, I am not able to see the pop-up. Please find the screenshot for your reference. Usually default screen is coming in Development mode, but when I ran the Installer package this seems to be not working.

Can't able to produce the repository as it needs the Azure login details and setup. Kindly assist.

Comment: Check your deployed config is correct. Also see what errors you're seeing in the browser debug output

Comment: I am not getting any error in the browser debug output. But the pop-up screen is empty